# Why doesn't Invoke-WebRequest follow redirect when ran from catch block

Tags: powershell

I'm running the code on PowerShell Core v6.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.14.5.

I have a list of websites I'm trying to validate using Invoke-WebRequest. Lets say the list contains the following websites

```
 http://www.google.com
 http://www.microsoft.com
 http://www.hp.com
 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=835028 http://samanage.bz
 http://samanage.agency
```

If I use the code below to validate the sites are accessible, everything works fine.

```powershell
$sites = Get-Content ./Sites.txt

    foreach ($site in $sites){
    $request = Invoke-Webrequest $site
    Write-Host "Status for $site is $($request.StatusDescription)."
}
```

After checking each website is valid, I wanted to see if the sites are redirected somewhere, so I added try/catch and limited maximum redirections to 0

```powershell
$sites = Get-Content ./Sites.txt

foreach ($site in $sites){

    try{
        $request = Invoke-WebRequest $site -MaximumRedirection 0
        $siteStatus = $request.StatusDescription
    }

    catch{
        Write-Host "$site is being redirected"
        $request = Invoke-WebRequest $site -Method HEAD

        # I actually use regex to pull out the destination site
        # from the Headers.Link attribute, but left it out for
        # simplicity

        $siteStatus = $request.Headers.Link
    }

    Write-Host "Status for $site is $siteStatus."
}
```

The expectation being that the first request would fail for any website using redirection and get caught in the catch block. Then the request would be rerun without the redirection limit and the redirect destination could be pulled from Headers.Link.

The code works fine for the first four entries, but the bottom two don't follow the redirection correctly and instead result in this error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Response status code does not indicate success: 302 (Found)

I've tried asking Google, but haven't found out what would cause `Invoke-WebRequest` to give different results when I run them inside the catch block.

Anybody have an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

`302` is a redirect status, so it seems like you're being redirected again. The default value for `-MaximumRedirection` is `5`; is it possible that there are more than 5 redirects happening? Perhaps an infinite redirect loop? You could try setting the number higher at first. You could also add a check in the `catch` to compare whether `$site` and `$siteStatus` are the same, but you'll have to decide which parts of the URL count as same or not (host name only, path, query, scheme, trailing slash, etc.). Casting as `[uri]` so you get some pre-filled properties might be helpful there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually thought this might be caused by redirection being more than 5 hops and that's why I tested the websites without try/catch. Without error handling, all sites resolve fine.